# Nivo bar graph - add a shared y axis?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using nivo responsive-bar to put a plot in my app. I've been asked to add a line showing the cumulative total on the same graph. Is there any way to do this? From the documentation I'm struggling to work out how to do it.

Here's the code I have so far (I've obfuscated the axis label and function names for security reasons!)

```
class CChart extends React.Component {
   render = () => {
     return (
       <div style={{ height: '40em' }}>
         <h3 className='text-center'>C</h3>
         <ResponsiveBar
           margin={{ top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 60, left: 80 }}
           data={this.props.results}
           indexBy='year'
           colorBy={() => '#1f77b4'}
           keys={['C']}
           enableLabel={false}
           axisLeft={{
             legend: 'C(millions)',
             legendPosition: 'center',
             legendOffset: -60,
             tickSize: 5,
             tickPadding: 15,
             format: v => Math.floor(v / 1000000).toLocaleString()
           }}
           axisBottom={{
             legend: 'Year',
             legendPosition: 'center',
             legendOffset: 50,
             tickSize: 5,
             tickPadding: 15,
        tickValues: this.props.results.map(x => x.year).filter(x => x % 5      === 0)
           }}
           theme={{
             axis: {
               fontSize: '1em',
               legendFontSize: '1.2em'
             }
           }}
           tooltipFormat={value => value.toLocaleString()}
           animate={false}
           markers={[
             { axis: 'y', value: 0 }
           ]}
         />
       </div>
     )
   }

   static propTypes = {
     results: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
       year: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
       C: PropTypes.number.isRequired
     })).isRequired
   }

   static mapStateToProps = state => ({
    results: getCResults(state)
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible currently (https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/139)

Answer (score 1):

According to the @plouc (the founder of the Nivo library), as of September, 2018 you should be able to compose graphs. 
https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/139

 (scroll down until Sept 12)